# Surfaces of general type with $h^1(-K_X)\neq 0$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, characteristic-2

By a result of Ekedahl, in characteristic 2 one may have minimal surfaces of general type such that $h^1(X,-K_X)\neq 0$ and $X$ is birational to an inseparable double cover of a rational surface. How can one construct such surfaces?